# Import list of IP, and then resolve-DNS for each of the IP address(es)

Tags: powershell

I wish to modify the below script, so the imported unique IP address from a text file can be translated into hostname in a separate.CSV file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Logs\Input\ -Filter *.csv |
    Get-Content |
            Sort-Object -Unique | Sort -desc |
                Set-Content -Path C:\LOGS\Unique-$($ColumnNames).txt
```

Input:

```
12.34.56.78
111.222.333.444
8.8.8.8
```

Output:

```
12.34.56.78 - hosta.domain.com
111.222.333.444 - hostX.net
8.8.8.8 - something wrong
```

Comment: So "input" is the content of the file?

Comment: Actually no, it gathers all content in the directory with the extension .CSV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input & output files are CSV, then you should make use of the `*-Csv` cmdlets for importing and exporting files in CSV format.

I'm assuming you want inputs and outputs similar to below.

### Input

*ips.csv*

```
12.34.56.78
111.222.333.444
8.8.8.8
```

### Output

*ips-hostnames.csv*

```
IpAddress,HostName
12.34.56.78,hosta.domain.com
111.222.333.444,hostX.net
8.8.8.8,No such host is known.
```

### Demo

```bsh
$inputDirectory = "C:\Input"
$outputDirectory = "C:\Output"

# Create output directory if it doesn't exist
if (-not(Test-Path -Path $outputDirectory -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $outputDirectory -ItemType Directory
}

# Go through each CSV file in input directory
foreach ($csv in Get-ChildItem -Path $inputDirectory -Filter *.csv -Recurse) {

    # Import CSV contents with IpAddress header
    $csvFile = Import-Csv -Path $csv.FullName -Header IpAddress

    # Get output path of CSV
    $csvName = Split-Path -Path $csv.FullName -LeafBase
    $csvOutputFileName = "{0}-{1}.csv" -f  $csvName, "hostnames"
    $csvOutputPath = Join-Path -Path $outputDirectory -ChildPath $csvOutputFileName
    
    # Export to CSV file with IpAddress & HostName headers
    & {
        foreach ($ip in $csvFile.IpAddress) {

            # Attempt to fetch DNS hostname
            try {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    IpAddress = $ip
                    HostName = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($ip).HostName
                }
            }

            # Could not resolve DNS hostname
            catch {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    IpAddress = $ip
                    HostName = $_.Exception.InnerException.Message
                }
            }
        }
    } | Export-Csv -Path $csvOutputPath -NoTypeInformation -UseQuotes AsNeeded
}
```

### Explanation

1. Import each CSV file contents with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7), making sure to set a header if the CSV file has no headers(seems to be the case from your input file).
2. Create a CSV output path. You can decide what this can be, but something like `ips-hostnames.csv` should work. We can use [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7) with `-LeafBase` to get the filename of the input CSV, then combine this with the output directory to create a full path using [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7).
3. Create a [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) to represent the output CSV columns. You can have 2 columns for your IP addresses and hostnames.
4. Use [`[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=netcore-3.1) to resolve an IP to a DNS hostname, assuming reverse DNS lookups are configured already. We can wrap this in a `try/catch` block to catch an exception if the method could not resolve the DNS, and set the hostname entry to the exception message.
5. Export output CSV files with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7).